# Series.unique() doesn't show all unique element but list(Series.unique() ) does?

Tags: pandas

I am trying to find unique values of some Series.  There are 10 unique values scattered among 200,000 observations, but when I try to find it using `Series.unique()`, only 8 values show up.  When I use `list(Series.unique())`, all 10 values show up.

What happened here?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by 'show up'? [`pandas.Series.unique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) returns an [`ndarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) object. When printing it to console, it shows up without commas between the elements. When printing a list, those commas are included, and may let it have greater horizontal width, visually implying a greater set.

Example terminal output:

```
>>> print('ndarray:', s.unique())
ndarray: [2 3 6 5 4 9 0]
>>> print('list:   ', list(s.unique()))
list:    [2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 9, 0]
```

If you want to check that they really are different, you can call [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) on it and compare them:

```
if set(Series.unique()) == set(list(Series.unique())):
    print('They have the same elements.')
else:
    print('They have different elements.')
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your explanation!